# Running Java Program on AWS (Amazon Web Services)

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I have a Java program which does **not** use any AWS services and solely communicates with a DBaaS outside of AWS, in my case IBM's Cloudant DBaaS. To host this java program on an AWS EC2 instance would I still be required to use the *AWS SDK for Java* or *AWS Toolkit for Eclipse* to develop the program?

Comment: Let me answer your question with another question: how would you communicate your program running on AWS  with the DBaaS database? Even if it would be physically possible would the program performance be acceptable?

Comment: Command line. My program is not a web application, it's really a batch process working with data from a Cloudant-hosted database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly don't need to use the SDK. You might find the Eclipse toolkit useful, depending on what you want to do with your EC2 instance, but probably the AWS web interface is enough for you.